# Before Update trigger throws an error

Tags: trigger

I want to delete record from custom object where name = new. I wrote simple apex trigger to delete this records however I am getting below error when execute.

> System.SObjectException: DML statement cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old:

Apex Trigger

```
trigger DuplicateTemp on Temp__c(before update) {
    List<Temp__c> tempToDelete = new List<Temp__c>();

    for(Temp__c temp: Trigger.New){
        If (temp.Name == 'New'){

            tempToDelete.add(temp);
        }
    }
         Database.delete(tempToDelete); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do dml on objects, that are in trigger at current transaction. To achieve it, you can collect ids of records, that you want to delete and then delete them, and do it on **after update**:

```
trigger DuplicateTemp on Temp__c(after update) {
    List<Id> tempToDeleteIds = new List<Id>();
    for(Temp__c temp: Trigger.New){
        If (temp.Name == 'New'){
            tempToDeleteIds.add(temp.Id);
        }
    }
    Database.delete(tempToDeleteIds); 
}
```